"feel" meaning "receive physical sensations"
"I felt that someone touched my shoulder."
Is this sentence grammatically acceptable? I know it is better to say, "I felt someone touch my shoulder." in order to sound more natural, though. I still would like to know whether the sentence is acceptable or not.

In formal contexts (like ESL exams) it might be better to use past perfect "had touched", but informally, simple past is fine. I don't think this is what you're asking though.

Oh, you know it well. Students tend to try to be very precise in grammar though I tell them not to, that much. The education system in Japan kind of force them to be that way, and their speaking ability grows so slowly...

It's grammatically correct but not very idiomatic.
We usually use I felt that... when feel has the sense 'have a belief or impression' - for example "Though she was polite, I felt that she was not pleased to see me". For a physical sensation, there is no need to include that.

Thank you very much for your comment. Now I know the difference.

In this context, it would mean that you had the mental impression that someone touched your shoulder, but not necessarily that you had any physical sensation of it.
To be explicit, in this case, a native speaker would not think that "felt" implied physical contact. For comparison, you could also say, "I felt that someone looked at my shoulder," or "I felt that someone touched someone else's shoulder," or even "I felt that someone disliked my shoulder," and they would be grammatically accurate in the same way and "felt" would have the same meaning in each of them: "to undergo passive experience of" (Merriam-Webster, v.t., 2a).
Another answer says that it's not idiomatic. I sort of disagree. I think that if this is what you meant, it's perfectly idiomatic, but it's also probably pretty unlikely that that's what you meant.

Thank you for your clarification. For me, it is enough to know that native speakers would not think that this "felt" implies physical contact. I think she meant it by saying "idiomatic".

Let's say that you're at a seance, trying to make contact with the spirit world, and you have the strange sensation that your shoulder is being touched. Afterwards,  you're not sure. Maybe it happened, maybe it was your imagination. If you wanted to tell someone about that experience:

It felt like someone touched my shoulder.

If you're pretty sure it happened:

I felt someone touch my shoulder.


Thank you for your funny clarification. I got to know the new word "seance".
